# TestNg Selenium- Find table column value dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Am looking for a way to fetch the column values dynamically using testng and selenium.
I have a 2 tables for displaying account details like account id , account name ,balance , available balance.
Table 1 is  for savings accounts and table 2 is for loan accounts.both table has balance and available balance column, but column position is different.

I want a single method which will accept the account id as argument (eg: id2),  and return the  balance of the  corresponding account ? eg: if I pass id2 it
should return 500 ,if  I pass id4 it should return 500.
Note : balance and available balance always be the last columns of the table .

```
<table id=”savings”>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>balance</th>
<th>available balance</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>id1</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>123</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>id2</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>510</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>






<table id=”loan”>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>nextpayment</th>
<th>balance</th>
<th>available balance</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>id3</td>
<td>first account</td>
<td>2018-09-21</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>123</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>id4</td>
<td>second account</td>
<td>2018-10-25</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>510</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you share your code that isn't working?  And explain why the code you share isn't working by sharing any relevant stack traces or other useful debug information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First, you can identify td using id and by using id element you can identify parent element in this way you will get the full row identified with a unique ID.

Sample XPath :

```
//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'id2')]]/tr 
//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'id4')]]/tr
```

Sample method which will give you balance and available balance :

```
 // Pass Id value as id1, id2 , id3, or id4
public void finddetailByID(String id)
{
    List <WebElement> tablerows= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'"+id+"')]]/td"));
    int rowsize=tablerows.size();
    String availabebalance=tablerows.get(rowsize).getText();
    String balance=tablerows.get(rowsize-1).getText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using the xpath rather getting the column collection.
Here is the code.

```
public void getBalanceById(String id){
   String balance= driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//td[normalize-space(.)='" + id + ']/ancestor::tr/td)[last()-1]")).gettext();
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Suraj Rao and Victor, got your point and will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get value cell from table with id='savings'

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://somethingURL");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //insert id here
    String id = "id2";

    //define table by id
    WebElement tbl = driver.findElement(By.id("savings"));

    //get row count
    List<WebElement> rows = tbl.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++) {
        List<WebElement> row = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        int columnCount = row.size();
        //check row contain td, not th
        if(columnCount > 0) {
            // 0=index id column from table with id 'savings'
            String getIDFromTable = row.get(0).getText();
            if(getIDFromTable.equals(id)){
                // 1=index balance column from table with id 'savings'
                String getBalance = row.get(1).getText();
                // 2=index available balance column from table with id 'savings'
                String getAvailableBalance = row.get(2).getText();
                System.out.println(getBalance);
                System.out.println(getAvailableBalance);
                break;
            }
        }
    }               
    driver.quit();
```