# Get specific value based on column & row name from dynamic Web table in which columns & rows position also dynamic

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have to print a specific value based on column and row names.
Bt the problem is that columns position and rows position changes every time. And table data is dynamic, values are changing continuously. All the values are not constant[my dynamic web table is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSXGd.jpg). and i want specific value of month April in year 2001.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide more data in your question for someone to help you.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem but needs more details.  For example, the HTML (or URL) of the page you are using?  Do you have any attempts to write the Selenium scripts that you could show us?

Comment: No I didn't have any attempt.

Comment: I think, you first need to write something by yourself, then, if you will not succeed, people here will help to fix/improve your script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNg Selenium- Find table column value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290959/testng-selenium-find-table-column-value-dynamically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the sample table based on the attached screenshot.

```html
<html>
 <table id='table1' border=" 1px solid black">
 <tr>  
  <th>Month/Year</th>
  <th>2003</th>
  <th>2004</th>
  <th>2001</th>
  <th>2005</th>
  <th>2002</th>
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
  <td>May</td>
  <td>122</td>
  <td>84</td>
  <td>7777</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>122</td>
 </tr>

 <tr> 
  <td>Feb</td>
  <td>45</td>
  <td>445</td>
  <td>565</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>122</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>April</td>
  <td>3556</td>
  <td>212</td>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>1546</td>
  <td>855</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <span>-----------------------------------------------</span>
 <table id='table2' border=" 1px solid black">
 <tr>  
  <th>Month/Year</th>
  <th>2002</th>
  <th>2001</th>
  <th>2003</th>
  <th>2004</th>
  <th>2005</th>
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
  <td>April</td>
  <td>120</td>
  <td>243</td>
  <td>221</td>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>65</td>
 </tr>

 <tr> 
  <td>May</td>
  <td>96</td>
  <td>146</td>
  <td>454</td>
  <td>452</td>
  <td>4566</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>March</td>
  <td>788</td>
  <td>139</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1001</td>
  <td>013</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>Feb</td>
  <td>552</td>
  <td>1245</td>
  <td>545</td>
  <td>41</td>
  <td>41</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Below is the xpath to get the value of "April/2001" from table 1.

```
//table[@id='table1']//td[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Month/Year']/preceding-sibling::th)+1 and normalize-space(.)='April']/ancestor::tr//td[position()=count(//table[@id='table1']//th[normalize-space(.)='2001']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

[image]
And xpath to get the value of "April/2001" from table 2.

```
//table[@id='table2']//td[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Month/Year']/preceding-sibling::th)+1 and normalize-space(.)='April']/ancestor::tr//td[position()=count(//table[@id='table2']//th[normalize-space(.)='2001']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

[image]
The only difference between the 2 xpaths' above is table id `**//table[@id='tableX**`. Please update the table locator as per your application values.
Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thank u so much I'll try this

Comment: @PoojaSavant Did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: i tried this bt its not working for my web table. bcz i dont know table data, only i have column & row names

Comment: Is it possible to share the html of table header and one row (with mocked data), so that I can check if the solution need any customization for you.

Comment: Updated the answer wit the data matching with your screenshot. Please share the mocked html table if the updated answer did not help you.