# Search text from element td and click button in the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, katalon-recorder

I need to find text inside td and click edit in the same line, example how to find base on ID AAA02 and click edit in the same line, or any another app or automate app to do this code. Im usually use katalon-recorder for automate browser.

```html
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>STATUS</td>
      <td>ACTION</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>AAA01</td>
      <td>ANDRE</td>
      <td>ACTIVE</td>
      <td><button type="submit">EDIT</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>YULIUS</td>
      <td>ACTIVE</td>
      <td><button type="submit">EDIT</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What things have you tried? You will get better results if you [follow this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to select the `Edit` button in the row with `ID` as `AAA02`.

```
//td[position()=count(//thead//td[normalize-space(.)='ID']/preceding-sibling::td)+1][normalize-space(.)='AAA02']/ancestor::tr//button[.='EDIT']
```

[image]

You can find the detailed explanation on xpath [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995924/get-specific-value-based-on-column-row-name-from-dynamic-web-table-in-which-co/55016381#55016381)

Comment: hello, thankyou for answer, do you have any contact? maybe i can ask more complex

Comment: You can join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209378/selnium-xpath) to discuss more on the complex issue that you want to solve.

Comment: btw, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side in my answer, if you feel this answered your question.